# Can I make Github action not to wait for CodeBuild's completion?

Tags: github-actions, aws-codebuild

I have used the below in workflow.yml and set up Github actions in my project.

```yaml
- name: Run CodeBuild
  uses: aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build@v1
  with:
    project-name: CodeBuildProjectName
    buildspec-override: path/to/buildspec.yaml or inline buildspec definition
    compute-type-override: compute-type
    environment-type-override: environment-type
    image-override: ecr-image-uri
    env-vars-for-codebuild: |
      custom,
      requester,
      event-name
  env:
    custom: my environment variable
    requester: ${{ github.actor }}
    event-name: ${{ github.event_name }}
```

This works as expected i.e. the intended AWS Codebuild job got triggered successfully.

My project has a requirement: Once the Codebuild job is triggered from Actions, the workflow should not wait for the Codebuild job to complete.

Is there a way to force the Actions not to wait? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like you have already opened an [issue](https://github.com/aws-actions/aws-codebuild-run-build/issues/131) on the repo of that action. Your requirement sounds like a feature request for that action. You may fork and modify yourself too.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. Let me see the possibilities to modify it myself.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to let the pipeline pass without it having to succeed. For that you can use the tag **allow_failure: true**

Official description:

> Use allow_failure to determine whether a pipeline should continue
> running when a job fails.
>
> To let the pipeline continue running subsequent jobs, use
> allow_failure: true. To stop the pipeline from running subsequent
> jobs, use allow_failure: false. When jobs are allowed to fail
> (allow_failure: true) an orange warning () indicates that a job
> failed. However, the pipeline is successful and the associated commit
> is marked as passed with no warnings.

For more read: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/

Comment: The question is about GitHub Actions, not GitLab CI. And, it's about not blocking until the build is complete. It's looking for a way to simply start the build and then finish it with a success exit code without waiting for the response.